# DevExpress MetroUI to WindowsUI

Tags: winforms, microsoft-metro, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Actually,I have developed my application in DevExpress MetroUIView.
Now I need to convert that into DevExpress WindowsUIView.
I am using the version 12.2.4.
I tried to convert my project by DevExpress `Project Converter` tool, 
but this line is not getting converted:

```
public DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI.MetroUIView MetroUIView1;
```

Is there any other option for converting from MetroUIView to WindowsUIView?

Comment: The Project converter tool should convert MetroUIView to WindowsUIView without any additional options. Please specify what the exactly is not converted...

Comment: I have
    public DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI.MetroUIView MetroUIView1;

It is not getting converted to WindowsUIView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the following lines (from FormXXX.Designer.cs):

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
//...
this.metroUIView1 = new DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI.MetroUIView(this.components);
//...
}
public DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI.MetroUIView metroUIView1;
```

to:

```
private void InitializeComponent() {
//...
this.metroUIView1 = new DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI.WindowsUIView(this.components);
//...
}
public DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI.WindowsUIView metroUIView1;
```

Then you can rename the `metroUIView1` variable to `windowsUIView1`.

The `DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI.MetroUIView` class is defined in DevExpress.XtraBars.v12.2.dll only for compatibility reasons (you can press F12 key to see it's declaration from metadata):

```
namespace DevExpress.XtraBars.Docking2010.Views.WindowsUI {
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Obsolete("You should use the WindowsUIView class")]
    public class MetroUIView : WindowsUIView {
        public MetroUIView();
        public MetroUIView(IContainer container);
    }
}
```